# Terminator could not find rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminator

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS.I have successfully installed ruby via rvm and rails.I can also see which version of rails and ruby in terminal by typing rails -v,ruby -v successively.On the other hand,I have installed terminator on my ubuntu and I have faced an error message while I was typing rails -v: 
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
When I have typed ruby -v,no error message,it prints the version,no problem.
Please be noted that I have already installed ruby and rails successfully and it works correctly with terminal.
Here are some pictures of the situation:

http://imageshack.us/f/819/screenshotfrom201206281.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/407/screenshotfrom201206281.png/

Comment: Normally is a bad idea to run the rails version from the package manager from your distribution, the same goes with ruby. The ruby version packaged from your distro should be used only as a dependency of other packages for your distro.

My suggestion is to install rvm (http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) and run rails from there, believe it WILL pay for itself in a couple of days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem while using rvm.
To resolve it you should add:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

to your ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem. Many of the commands of my rails environment were not working on Terminator and the following solved it for me.

Right click on the Terminator window. **Preferences > Profiles > Command** and check "**Run command as login shell**"

Please refer to the following post as to why this works https://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal

Here is some more insight on shell login from RVM https://rvm.io/support/faq#shell_login

Comment: Are those the instructions for the Gnome Terminal, and not Terminator, right?

Answer (score 1):

I also enconter this problem like you , rails can run on terminal but not termilator, i can't resolve it.  So I use tmux instead of termilator which also can splits windows and even more stronger.